# Making root being bind mounted

Tags: dual-boot, chroot, initramfs, root-filesystem, bind-mount

I have `XUbuntu` and `Arch` on a laptop, I'm sharing /boot partition between these distros mounting it on `/mnt/boot` and bind-mounting `/mnt/boot/xubuntu` or `/mnt/boot/arch` onto `/boot`; it works fine even when updating `initramfs`, no manual intervention never.

I would like to do the same for `/`, for example, having `/xubuntu` and `/arch` directories on the root partition and selecting one of them on each initrd. I know it is not the same case as for `/boot`, because initrd must first mount that filesystem on `/test`, for example, and later a pivot_root must be issued to make `/test/xubuntu` or `/test/arch` the new `/`.

It is possible to share `/` between two distros in the way described above?

Comment: seems to me to be a duplicate of
[Boot Linux system from a subdirectory on a partition?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/39423/boot-linux-system-from-a-subdirectory-on-a-partition)